# Find variables defined in other module (python)

Tags: python, python-module, traceback, doctest

I have a module testing system in Python where individual modules call something like:

```
class Hello(object):
     _DOC_ATTR = { 'greeting': '''
         a greeting message.

         >>> h = Hello()
         >>> h.greeting = 'hi there'
         >>> h.greeting
         'hi there'
         ''' }

     def __init__(self):
         self.greeting = "hello"

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
     # tests here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tester
    tester.test(Test)
```

inside tester, I run the tests in Test along with a doctest on `"__main__"`. This works great and has worked fine for a long time.  Our specialized _DOC_ATTR dictionary documents individual attributes on the function when we build into Sphinx. However, doctests within this dictionary are not called. What I would like to do is within `tester.test()` to run doctests on the values in each class's _DOC_ATTR as well.

The problem that I'm having is trying to find a way within `tester.test()` to figure out all the variables (specifically classes) defined in `__main__`. I've tried looking at relevant places in `traceback` to no avail.  I thought that because I was passing in a class from `__main__`, namely `__main__.Test` that I'd be able to use the `.__module__` from `Test` to get access to the local variables there, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I would rather not need to alter the call to `tester.test(Test)` since it's used in hundreds of modules and I've trained all the programmers working on the project to follow this paradigm.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I may have found the answer:

```
import inspect
stacks = inspect.stack()
if len(stacks) > 1:
    outerFrame = stacks[1][0]
else:
    outerFrame = stacks[0][0]
localVariables = outerFrame.f_locals
for lv in list(localVariables.keys()):
    lvk = localVariables[lv]
    if (inspect.isclass(lvk)):
        docattr = getattr(lvk, '_DOC_ATTR', None)
        if docattr is not None:
            # ... do something with docattr ...
```

Another solution: since we are passing the "Test" class in, and in order to run there needs to be a "runTest" function defined, one could also use the `func_globals` on that function.  Note that it cannot be a function inherited from a superclass, such as `__init__`, so it may have limited functionality for wider use cases.

```
import inspect
localVariables = Test.runTest.func_globals
for lv in list(localVariables.keys()):
    lvk = localVariables[lv]
    if (inspect.isclass(lvk)):
          #### etc.
```